# Need idea to use variable JS outside and use button to send data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, variables

This script save the id of the row I clicked. But now I would like to do :
"If I click on `buttonmodif` then change url and send the variable `number` (which is the id of the row) into the url (and the next page) . I'm not sure how to do it.

I would like to save the variable `number` outside the script and when I click on `buttonmodif` I send my variable to another url.

Thank you for your answer!

**HTML FILE** :

```
<div id="page-wrapper" style=" padding-left: 20px">
    <form method="post" name="employes1" action="employes.php">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class=" text-center">
                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-default"><?php echo '<a href="employesajout.php" > Ajouter un employé </a>'; ?></button>


                    <button type="submit" name="buttonmodif" id="modifon"> Mofidier informations</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Supprimer employé</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Créer un contrat de travail</button>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row table-responsive">

                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="MyTable">
                    <thead class="-inverse">

                    <?php
                    $rep = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * from employee');
                    $rep->execute();
                    $resultat = $rep->fetchAll();
                    ?>


                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Nom</th>
                        <th>Prénom</th>
                        <th>Résidence</th>
                        <th>NAS</th>
                        <th>Date d'entré</th>
                        <th>Heure /semaine</th>
                        <th>Salaire brute</th>
                        <th>Salaire net</th>
                        <th>Vacance (s)</th>
                        <th>Email</th>


                    </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    <?php foreach ($resultat as $row) {

                        echo "
                  <tr class ='clickable-row'>
                    <td>$row[0]</td>
                    <td>$row[1]</td>
                    <td>$row[2]</td>
                    <td>$row[3]</td>
                    <td>$row[4]</td>
                    <td>$row[5]</td>
                    <td>$row[6]</td>
                    <td>$row[7]</td>
                    <td>$row[8]</td>
                    <td>$row[9]</td>
                    <td>$row[10]</td>
                </tr>";

                    };

                    ?>

                    <script>

                        $(document).ready(function ($) {

                            $(".clickable-row").click(function () {

                                var number = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').children().eq(0).text());
                                console.log(number);

                            });


                            // active click hilight
                            $('td').click(function () {
                                $('tr').removeClass('active');
                                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                            });


                        });

                    </script>


                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the variable outside the `click` function. Then bind a `click` handler on the `buttonmodif` button that uses the variable. You can add a `type="hidden"` input to the form, and put the value there.

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    var number;

    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        number = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').children().eq(0).text());
        console.log(number);
    });

    $("#modifon").click(function() {
        $("#hiddenfield").val(number);
    });
});
```

Comment: I used :  document.getElementById("hiddenfield").value = number;
and create an input hidden like you said, it's working.
I guess it is another way to do it ?
Thank you Barmar !

Comment: Yeah, that's the plain Javascript way. But you're using jQuery, so I wrote it in that syntax.